# Type data into text box using HP UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to set some data automatically into the text box and then press a button in that using HP UFT, but now problem is that when i am do it manually then a button is enable and when i do same thing with the HP UFT then a button is disable. Here is the screenshot for that : http://screencast.com/t/IKl1PxZkhc

I think a button is enabled only when we enter a data using key board. So how can i resolve this issue ?

Please help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable an object by using its native properties.

Try this.

```
Browser("browser").Page("page").WebButton("button").Object.disabled=False
```

Comment: Don't forget to up vote to make this useful for others. Thanks,happy testing